# Convert Image to Base64 for Json Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, uiimage, base64, swift3

I need to convert an `UIImage` to `base64` for send it on a `JSON`. My problem is the conversion. My code:

```
//Proof #1
let base64String = imageData?.base64EncodedData(options: .endLineWithLineFeed)
//Proof #2 
let base64String = imageData?.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithLineFeed)

let dataJson = ["patient_image": ["title": titleInfo, "description": descriptionInfo, "patient_id": globalID, "images_attributes": ["file": base64String]]]

    let url = NSURL(string: "MY_URL")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST

    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dataJson, options: .prettyPrinted)

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

I tried both ways `Swift 3` provides for convert an image to `base64`, but with both i get the same error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)'
```

Can somebody help me? I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the  options:

```
let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedString()
```

Complete code:

```
/*
let imageData = Data()
let titleInfo = "test"
let descriptionInfo = "test"
let globalID = "test"
*/

let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedString()

let dataJson = ["patient_image": ["title": titleInfo, "description": descriptionInfo, "patient_id": globalID, "images_attributes": ["file": base64String]]]

let url = NSURL(string: "MY_URL")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
request.httpMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST

request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dataJson, options: .prettyPrinted)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Also (independent of your issue) the key name `images_attributes` sounds like it expects an array.

Comment: let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedString()
Cool, it helps me a lot. But I'd like to know why and what's the difference if we use option?